# How do I use a json tag as a parameter in benthos

Tags: benthos

```
    input:
      generate:
        mapping: root = {"id":48554}
    
    pipeline:
      processors:
        - http:
            url: https://example.com/**use_id_here_from_root**
            verb: GET
            retries: 5
            timeout: 10s
            retry_period: 2s
```

I tried using {{.id}}, eq.${! json("id") } but both of these dont seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The `http` processor [`url` field](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/processors/http#fields) supports [interpolation functions](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/configuration/interpolation#bloblang-queries). You should be on the right track with `${! json("id") }`, but there might be something wrong with how your test setup.

This config worked for me:

```yaml
input:
  generate:
    count: 1
    interval: 0s
    mapping: root = {"id":48554}

pipeline:
  processors:
    - http:
        url: http://127.0.0.1:6666/${! json("id") }
        verb: GET
        retries: 5
        timeout: 10s
        retry_period: 2s

output:
  stdout: {}
```

To test it, I ran `nc` in a loop:

```bash
> while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" | nc -l 127.0.0.1 6666; done
```

then I ran `benthos`:

```bash
> benthos -c test.yaml
```

and I got the following output from `nc`:

```
GET /48554 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:6666
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"id":48554}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mihai I was able to solve the problem by using `${! json(\"id\") }` .